# Memset In C Using Sizeof Operator :

Tags: c

Here is a struct :

```
typedef struct tag_device_sys
{
    char device[STRING_SIZE];
    int id;
    char category;
} device_sys;
```

For memset, which one should be used from below ?

```
memset(dev_sys, 0, (size_t)NUM_DEVICES * sizeof(device_sys));
```

or

```
memset(dev_sys, 0, (size_t)NUM_DEVICES * sizeof(dev_sys));
```

What are the differences ?

Comment: The code you posted wont work at all. Either dev_sys is a pointer, then sizeof(dev_sys) does not evaluate to the size of the structure. Otherwise, if dev_sys is not a pointer, memset will complain that the first parameter has to be a one.

Comment: What is dev_sys? What role does NUM_DEVICES play in your question?

Answer (score 9):

I like to use objects as arguments to `sizeof`

```
struct whatever *ptr;
/* ... */
ptr = malloc(nelems * sizeof *ptr);
memset(ptr, 0, nelems * sizeof *ptr);
```

The advantage over using a parenthesized type is that the code only needs to be changed at one place should the type of the data change

```
struct before_change *ptr;
/* ... */
ptr = malloc(nelems * sizeof (struct before_change));
memset(ptr, 0, nelems * sizeof (struct before_change));
```

Comment: How about using `calloc()` instead of malloc.

Comment: @Athabaska: `ptr = calloc(nelems, sizeof *ptr);` and you don't need the `memset`. If that's really wanted, I prefer `calloc` over the pair `malloc`/`memset`: I used both above mainly for illustration purposes.

Comment: @Athabaska: The advantage of @pmg's approach holds equally well for `calloc` as it does for `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

`dev_sys` is a pointer. `sizeof(dev_sys)` will just give you size of the pointer for your platform.

Answer (score 0):

`memset(dev_sys, 0, (size_t)NUM_DEVICES * sizeof(device_sys))` should work if dev_sys was malloced as `(NUM_DEVICES * sizeof(device_sys))`

Answer (score 0):

Definitely

```
memset(dev_sys, 0, (size_t)NUM_DEVICES * sizeof(device_sys));
```

There are a few cases, if you have:

1) Static array, using sizeof in that context:

```
device_sys dev_sys[NUM_DEVICES] = { /* init data * };
...
sizeof(dev_sys);
```

In this case, sizeof operator will give the entire size of the array, so you will essentially end up with:

```
NUM_DEVICES * (NUM_DEVICES * sizeof(device_sys))
```

2) or you have a dynamically allocated piece of memory acccessed through a pointer, OR you are in the context of a function call where dev_sys is passed as a function argument. Either way:

`sizeof(dev_sys)` will give the size of a pointer (in the first, because it IS a pointer, in the second, due to pointer decay), whcih will most likely not be what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

```
memset(dev_sys, 0, (size_t)NUM_DEVICES * sizeof(*dev_sys));
```

Always works as the way you've written it suggests `dev_sys` is either a pointer or an array. `sizeof(*dev_sys)` gives us the sizeof the first element.

In any case, I would write is as either

```
device_sys dev_sys[NUM_DEVICES];

memset(dev_sys, 0, (size_t) NUM_DEVICES * sizeof(*dev_sys));
```

or

```
device_sys *dev_sys = (device_sys *) calloc(NUM_DEVICES, sizeof(*dev_sys));
```

depending on if you want `dev_sys` on the stack or on the heap

Answer (score 0):

Richard Stevens (Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, etc) suggests bzero() or your own portable equivalent because it avoids the common bug of swapping memset() arguments.  You could even make a single-arg macro ZERO(obj) that did `bzero(obj, sizeof(*obj))`.  Or  `ZERO(object) (memset (&(object), '\0', sizeof ((object))))` perhaps is an alternative. Along those lines, nice way to make bugs less possible.

Comment: `memset` is standard C however whereas `bzero` is merely standard POSIX.

Comment: Right, that's why you might do your own portable equivalent. It's only one line of code to do that.